# Multiple event on same classes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, textarea, append

I have multiple `<textarea>` generated dynamically with jQuery (.append).

When I append a new `<textarea>` I also add some `<div class="action">` to them, so it look like this :

```
<textarea>...</textarea>
<div class="action">Click to add action to text areas</div>

<textarea>...</textarea>
<div class="action">Click to add action to text areas</div>

<textarea>...</textarea>
<div class="action">Click to add action to text areas</div>

...
```

Now I would like to do add something inside the textarea when a User click on the div "action"

I've done this by :

```
$(document).on("click",".action", function() //this will apply to all anchor tags
{ 
        $(this).prev('textarea')
        .val($('textarea')
        .val() + 'NEW TEXT');  
});
```

The problem is that it only add once the `"NEW TEXT"` inside the `<textarea>` immediately before my div.

And when I click again on the `".action"` div nothing happens so I would like to click many times on the .action div to add my NEW TEXT again and again

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your line

```
.val($('textarea')
```

That is telling jQuery to find *a* textarea, not *the* textarea whose value you are modifying. Creating a local var inside the function should clarify it for you:

```
$(document).on("click", ".action", function() { 
    var $ta = $(this).prev('textarea');
    $ta.val($ta.val() + "\nNew Text");
});
```